# Problem using json_array_elements to extract values from array of JSON Objects in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-16

I have the following code in which I am trying to extract JSON as follows:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp2;
 CREATE TEMP  table tmp2 (
      c TEXT
    );

insert into tmp2 values
(        
N'{"SerialNumber":"907578","SoftwareVersion":"1.2.777","Build":"4829","ProductCode":"TR-3500-A","BuildDate":null,"Description":"Study desk","ConnectionType":2,"Capabilities":[2,3],
        "ChannelListDto":[
            {"ChannelId":0,"ConversionType":0,"DeviceSerialNumber":null,"Dimension":"","FixedName":null,"Name":"test2","InstrumentationChannel":-1,"IsAlarmable":false,"IsInternal":true,"IsEnableable":false,"IsEnabled":false,"JournalledReadingBytes":0,"LowerLimit":null,"Precision":null,"Symbol":"","TypeId":5,"UpperLimit":null},
            {"ChannelId":1,"ConversionType":0,"DeviceSerialNumber":null,"Dimension":"","FixedName":null,"Name":null,"InstrumentationChannel":-1,"IsAlarmable":false,"IsInternal":true,"IsEnableable":false,"IsEnabled":false,"JournalledReadingBytes":0,"LowerLimit":null,"Precision":null,"Symbol":"","TypeId":5,"UpperLimit":null},
            {"ChannelId":2,"ConversionType":0,"DeviceSerialNumber":null,"Dimension":"","FixedName":null,"Name":null,"InstrumentationChannel":-1,"IsAlarmable":false,"IsInternal":true,"IsEnableable":false,"IsEnabled":false,"JournalledReadingBytes":0,"LowerLimit":null,"Precision":null,"Symbol":"","TypeId":5,"UpperLimit":null}
         ]
        }'
)
```

Now i want to use some code to extract the information from each of the elements in the ChannelListDTo as follows:

```sql
select c::json ->> 'SerialNumber' as SerialNumber,
       cto ->> 'ChannelId'::INT   AS channelid,
       cto ->> 'ChannelName'      AS ChannelName
from tmp2
CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(c::json ->'ChannelListDto') Channels(cto);
```

However I am getting the following error:

> ```
> [2024-01-11 17:54:14] [22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "ChannelId"
> [2024-01-11 17:54:14] Position: 122
> ```

I want to get the following results:

```
DeviceSerialNumber channelID   ChannelName                             IsInternal        
------------------ ----------- --------------------------------------- ----------- 
907578             0           test2                                   1          
907578             1                                                   1           
907578             2                                                   1
```

I have tried the following :

```sql
select c::json ->> 'SerialNumber' as SerialNumber,
       Channels.cto --> 'ChannelID',
from tmp2
CROSS JOIN LATERAl json_array_elements(c::json ->'ChannelListDto') Channels(cto);
```

And this yields the following:

| serialnumber | cto |
| --- | --- |
| 907578 | "{""ChannelId"":0,""ConversionType"":0,""DeviceSerialNumber"":null,""Dimension"":"""",""FixedName"":null,""Name"":""test2"",""InstrumentationChannel"":-1,""IsAlarmable"":false,""IsInternal"":true,""IsEnableable"":false,""IsEnabled"":false,""JournalledReadingBytes"":0,""LowerLimit"":null,""Precision"":null,""Symbol"":"""",""TypeId"":5,""UpperLimit"":null}" |
| 907578 | "{""ChannelId"":1,""ConversionType"":0,""DeviceSerialNumber"":null,""Dimension"":"""",""FixedName"":null,""Name"":null,""InstrumentationChannel"":-1,""IsAlarmable"":false,""IsInternal"":true,""IsEnableable"":false,""IsEnabled"":false,""JournalledReadingBytes"":0,""LowerLimit"":null,""Precision"":null,""Symbol"":"""",""TypeId"":5,""UpperLimit"":null}" |
| 907578 | "{""ChannelId"":2,""ConversionType"":0,""DeviceSerialNumber"":null,""Dimension"":"""",""FixedName"":null,""Name"":null,""InstrumentationChannel"":-1,""IsAlarmable"":false,""IsInternal"":true,""IsEnableable"":false,""IsEnabled"":false,""JournalledReadingBytes"":0,""LowerLimit"":null,""Precision"":null,""Symbol"":"""",""TypeId"":5,""UpperLimit"":null}" |

So how can I extract the individual elements (ChannelID, ConversionType, IsInternal etc) out of the ChannelListDTO array of JSON Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT c::json ->> 'SerialNumber' AS "SerialNumber",
       (cto ->> 'ChannelId')::INT AS "ChannelId",
       cto ->> 'Name'             AS "ChannelName"
FROM tmp2, json_array_elements(c::json ->'ChannelListDto') AS "Channels"(cto);
```

| SerialNumber | ChannelId | ChannelName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 907578 | 0 | test2 |
| 907578 | 1 | *null* |
| 907578 | 2 | *null* |

1. As [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77821955/5298879), you need parentheses to make sure it's the output of `cto->>'ChannelId'` that gets cast to `::int`. Otherwise the cast takes precendence, so you end up first attempting this `'ChannelId'::int` before it's given to `->>`, which gives you the error since that text won't work as a number.
2. You can pretty safely trade `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` for just a comma `,` - the fact that the set-returning function relies on a field taken from `tmp2` implies the rest.
3. You need to [double-quote all your mixed-case identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), otherwise they will all get folded to lowercase.
4. It seems that you actually wanted `cto->>'Name'`, because the json you showed doesn't have a `'ChannelName'` key in it.
5. The `-->` in `Channels.cto --> 'ChannelID',` isn't an operator. You just selected the entire `Channels.cto` and then `--` started an [end-of-line comment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS).

[Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HuFdABgI)

Answer (score 0):

```
(cto ->> 'ChannelId')::int
```

You are trying to cast the key text 'ChannelId' to `integer` instead of the returned value. The above fetches the value first then casts it to an integer.